# Compute $\int_\gamma \big(\frac{z}{z-1}\big)^ndz$ where $\gamma(t):=1+e^{it}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I need to compute

$$\int_\gamma \bigg(\frac{z}{z-1}\bigg)^n dz$$

where

$$\gamma(t): [0,2 \pi] \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$$ is defined via

$$t \mapsto 1+e^{it}$$

So I appeal to

$\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) d \gamma(t)$ and I obtain

\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \bigg( \frac{z}{z-1} \bigg)^n dz &= \int_0^{2\pi} \bigg(\frac{e^{it}}{1+e^{it}-1}\bigg )^ni e^{it} dt\\
&=\int_0^{2 \pi}(1)^n i e^{i t} dt\\
&=e^{i t} \bigg\vert_0^{2 \pi}\\
&= 1-1\\
&=0
\end{align}

Did I do this correctly?

EDIT: I did not substitute in the $\gamma$ correctly, currently working on it!

Comment: That is not correct, $z/(z-1) = (e^{it}-1)/e^{it}$.

Comment: OH MY GOSH, shoot I forgot to substitute in all of $\gamma$ up top!! @MartinR thanks!!!!! Going to redo it now!

Comment: It would be much easier with the residue theorem ...

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4106954/42969. Here is another one:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2605249/42969

Comment: Notice that $\int_\gamma z^n (z-1)^{-n}dz$ gives you the coefficient of $(z-1)^{n-1}$ in the Taylor expansion of $z^n$ around $1$ times $2\pi i$. Since the expansion is $z^n = (z-1+1)^n = (z-1)^n + n(z-1)^{n-1} +\cdots$ that coefficient is $2\pi in $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$No, this is not a correct methodology. You substituted: $$\frac{z}{z-1}=\frac{e^{it}}{1+e^{it}-1}$$Where instead you should have substituted: $$\frac{z}{z-1}=\frac{\color{red}{1+}e^{it}}{1+e^{it}-1}$$

With this, you'd get: $$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{1+e^{it}}{e^{it}}\right)^n(ie^{it})\d t\\&=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it}(1+e^{-it})^n\d t\\&=i\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{(1-k)it}\d t\\&=i\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(2\pi\delta_{k,1})\\&=2\pi in\end{align}$$

However, with complex integration I seriously do not recommend this type of approach - you're in a perfect position to use the residue theorem here. Your contour encloses the order-$n$ pole that is at $z=1$. The integral is therefore equal to, using the standard pole-residue calculation formula: $$\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to1}\frac{\d^{n-1}}{\d z^{n-1}}z^n=2\pi in$$

Comment: yes I saw my mistake. thanks!